# No module named 'pandastable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, instalacion

Me acabo de cambiar de ordenador y tras ejecutar pip install pandastable,pip3 install pandastable y python -m pip install pandastable y salir el mensaje de Requeriment already satisfied. Al intentar importar el modulo me encuentro con el error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandastable'`

Tengo Anaconda instalado y python 3.7. Todos los demas modulos si me deja importarlos y ejecutarlos con normalidad.

Al ejecutar pip freeze me sale lo siguiente:
`pandastable==0.12.2.post1`

El mismo codigo se ejecutaba en otro ordenador sin problema alguno así que ese no es el problema

Comment: Asegurate de que ejecutas el mismo intérprete, en el script que te falla pon `import sys;print(sys.executable)` al principio de todo y mira la ruta que te muestra, luego en la terminal del sistema ejecuta  `python -m pip debug` y mira la ruta de la línea `sys.executable` si no coinciden usas un intérprete distinto del que has instlado `pandastable`. Si usas Anaconda instala los paquetes con `conda` y no uses intérpretes externos o al contrario, mezclar ambas cosas si no tenemos muy claro que intérprete o env estmos usando en cada momento solo trae éstos problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla. Al final era lo que tu decias, y buscando en internet he visto que podia instalar pip dentro de conda ya que pandastable no se puede instalar con conda. Ahora funciona de maravilla, muchisimas gracias